# Jquery making things happen while side scrolling (scrollto.js) - only works if scrolling slowly

Tags: jquery, scrollto, parallax

On a horizontal parallax site using jquery scrollTo(awesome...)  Am attempting to use the windowsize values AND scrollLeft values in making decisions knowing the current page width - even if resized.  That's all working.

When certain window widths are hit or moved through while scrolling left to right, I want to eventually set a value on nav items to provide guidepost to the next mark.  Using alerts/test codes as shown below to verify that my points are hitting.  And they are - IF SCROLLING REALLY SLOW.

Any ideas on catching these numbers cleanly and reliably?  Seems like it's firing so fast that jquery just not getting it.  Or am I not viewing this correctly?

```
function parallaxScroll(){

    var scrolledX = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    var win0 = 0;
    var win1 = windowsize;
    var win2 = windowsize * 2;
    var win3 = windowsize * 3;

    if (scrolledX == win1) {
        $("#test").text("mark1");
    }
    if (scrolledX == win2) {
        $("#test").text("mark2");
    }
    if (scrolledX == win3) {
        $("#test").text("mark3");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to catch an exact size. Look for the size, and anything larger - for example, if `win1` is 100, it'll fire at 100-199, then for `win2` if it's at 200-299, and so on.

Note I also check the window sizes largest to smallest (you can do them smallest to largest, then just be sure to change `>` to `<` and add an extra check for sizes larger than `win3`.

Also, make your checks `if ... else if ... else` statemnts so you don't accidentally fire it multiple times (win3 is larger than win2, so win2 would fire even at win3).

```
function parallaxScroll(){

  var scrolledX = $(window).scrollLeft();
  var windowsize = $(window).width();

  var win0 = 0;
  var win1 = windowsize;
  var win2 = windowsize * 2;
  var win3 = windowsize * 2;

  if (scrolledX >= win3) {
    $("#test").text("mark3");
  }
  else if (scrolledX >= win2) {
    $("#test").text("mark2");
  }
  else {
    $("#test").text("mark1");
  }

}
```

Comment: Spot on - face palm for me and a thank you to you.  It's rolling beautifully.